# How to use subversion effectively as a web developer?

Tags: svn

I am a web developer. Currently I am working with a web designer.The designers is doing all the template designing,multimedia works etc.My job is to use these templates and work on them with php. 
    We are not using any subversion system. But we despirately need one to work simultaneously on one file.My designer colleague uses dreamweaver editer and I use netbeans. Is it possible to use subversion in an effective way to solve the above problem? And how can the subversion be helpful in our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to get started with version control systems. svn is a relatively easy version control system to get started with it. If you want to start using svn, I highly recommend you to read the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

I don't know much about GUI subversion tools, but [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) seems to be fairly popular with devs (that I know of) who use Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for version control in general. So to make it clear, Subversion is one of the version control tools.

Version Control is important even when you are just working alone. Setup a repo, and keep committing whenever you have done some level of atomic work.

In your case, both you and the designer should work out of working copies of the same repo. You can use command line client or GUI clients like TortoiseSVN or IDE plugins ( Netbeans should have, not sure about DreamWeaver). So when each of you commit and make changes, Subversion or other version control tool, will help you make sure your changes are applied to updated version and helps you resolve conflicts etc.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* create 2 branches off of your main trunk, you work on one branch, and the designer on the other.  Merge them both into main when each are done their respective tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I read an article about this kind of situation once: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/revisioncontrol/

To be sure, you do need version control.